# How to deploy/debug iPhone App directly to iPhone device without IDP membership?

Tags: iphone, debugging

Can you show me how to deploy/debug and iphone application using xcode but without having to pay 99$. I'm doing this for the study purpose. 
I've seen a guide which help to deploy iphone application to iPhone device(e.g: http://www.vinodlive.com/2009/01/16/how-to-deploy-an-iphone-application-without-an-idp-membership/). However this guide doesn't help me to run/debug the application using Xcode, so it's quite inconvenient.
Some of my friends said that it's possible to run/debug iphone app to iPhone device using XCode and without IDP membership.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you asked the friends who say it's possible?

Comment: I would pay the $99, if your serious it's a great investment towards your future.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend on developing for the app store ever, I would pay the fee. If you can write, and get accepted, a halfway decent app, you'll have little trouble earning back that 99 bones of initial investment.

I wouldn't wait ~two weeks to have an app reviewed for the store if it had only been tested on a jailbroken iphone using some hack. Too risky...

Answer (score 1):

Apple designed the system the way they did to protect developers from piracy. It's inconvenient because you're not supposed to do it.

I'm not trying to say that you're doing something wrong or illegal, but you're just trying to bypass something that is in place to stop app-theft :)

Comment: bwuhahahaha
now that's funny.

Answer (score 0):

While not really a good thing, your best bet may be to jailbreak your phone. This will void your warranty and I'm pretty sure a kitten somewhere will die because another iPhone has been jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

Your stated goal is to debug on a device using XCode without paying $99 to Apple:

Assuming it's for quasi-official study purposes and you can find a cooperative university instructor to sponsor you or undertake some kind of directed study, you could try the [iPhone Developer University Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/university.html).

It's 'free,' but my guess is that the required hoops and time would make the $99/year for the regular program seem pretty reasonable. (I think the same goes for any jailbreaking solution, but I do remember what it was like to have neither a salary nor any competing demands on my time).