# iPhone development

Tags: iphone, macos, ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch.

I have a Mac.

I want to put an iPod touch app I write with my Mac on my iPod touch.

I don't plan to sell it on the Apple store.

I don't plan to distribute it to other people.

Is there anyway to do this without paying apple $99?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105095/how-to-deploy-debug-iphone-app-directly-to-iphone-device-without-idp-membership , and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465330/what-does-the-iphone-developer-program-give-me-over-and-above-simple-registration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer NO.

To download an app to a device you need to sign it, and the only way to sign is to sign up for the dev programme

Answer (score 3):

No if you  do not jailbreak your phone.

Answer (score 3):

Not without jailbreaking the iPod Touch which would violate all sorts of agreements :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the apple developer account (for $99) to code sign your application. Without this you will not be able to install it on a physical device, only on the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask a fellow registered iPhone developer to help you out by signing it then sending it back to you so you can [install it like a typical ad-hoc distributed app](http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution).

Answer (score 1):

No, I'll need to buy a development license and you can put your app in your iPod!

Answer (score 0):

Get a guy who has paid $99. Tell him to hook you up with a provisioned profile for your app, registering your device with the app name.

Install the provisioned profile file, and the app from xcode and you still have your clean phone.